# Making squares in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to write a program that will ask the user for a size of a square and then print out a square that has that many *'s.

For example,

Size?

3

Then it prints out a 3 x 3 square of *'s.

I need to also use for and while loops.

Thanks

Comment: You aren't trying hard enough.

Comment: Before you learn how to make a square, learn how to make a straight line of `*`'s. E.g. `3` = `***`. Simplify the problem and then build upon it.

Answer (score 1):

**Working code :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class patternBox {

    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of row / column : ");
        int row = input.nextInt(); // take user input
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) { // outer loop for row change
            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) // inner loop for * print
            {
                System.out.print("*");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

> Read: How to get input from user using [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)